# Is it possible on ELK to group snapshots and recover ignoring existing index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

in my project all ELK index snapshots are created dailly and with a 30 days window. It's not incremental. A snapshot done at January 30th will have index from 1st-30th Jan.

The problem now, is that we need to recover a full year, so is there any way to group the snapshots, merge them,etc, so recover all year in a single operation or we have to recover 12-13 snapshots?

Besides, we already have recovered some days from that year, so we have conflicts when we try to recover. Is there any way to ignore existing index?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate that's not possible right now in ELK, there's no option in the actual version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).